# TkInter create_rectangle() fixed size

Tags: python, tkinter

When using this function call in TkInter:

```
canvas.create_rectangle(canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x0+xsize, y0+ysize,
    outline="black", width=outline_width)
```

I want a rectange I can predict the size of. The problem is that depending on `outline_width`, the overall rectangle size varies.

For example if I keep constant

```
(xsize, ysize) = (20,20)
```

while varying `outline_width`, I get strange sizes. For example `outline_width=1` gives a 21px square, while using `outline_width=4` gives a 24px square.
This is quite an issues for me because if I cannot predict the size of my rectangle (that is, the size including the outline), my whole drawing is affected.

It would look like the total x width of the rectangle for example would be determined by (`xsize+outline_width`). But then another issue is that the position of the top-left corner of the rectange varies too depending on outline width.

Any solution to accurately determine where the rectangle will land in terms of top-left corner, and determining the final size as well?

EDIT: Included a picture. Notice how the rectangle "begins" at two completely different positions from the window (on the X axis), drawed a red line for reference.

[image]

I would really like that the top-left corner stays the same regardless of my value of `outline_width`. Or at least be able to know how much it will shift to right so I can change my coordinates to compensate for it.

Thanks

Comment: "the position of the top-left corner of the rectange varies too depending on outline width" How does it vary?

Comment: Cannot tell you exactly how it varies because thats exactly what my question is all about (I don't know), but it clearly does. For example if I use an outline_width of 3, the coord at which my rectangle "begins" x-wise is 9, while if I use an outline_width of 10, it "begins" at 5. Doesn't seem to make much sense to me (measured relatively to a truly fixed point on the window).

Comment: This is interesting - I don't think I would call this an outline width so much as a border width, because it appears that half of the stroke width is inside the border and half is outside. You may have to roll your own if you want a more predictable behavior...

Comment: @Wayne Werner yes it does not make much sense to me either to call it "outline" i will have to resort to making my own square function made out of 4 line segments probably

Comment: @Yannick Not sure if it would work any better, but you might consider just drawing 2px larger boxes outside the box that you draw with a an outline width of 1px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rectangle is a 2D range.  With no outline, create_rectangle treats the first 2 numbers as start values and the next 2 as stop values, as with Python's range(start, stop) function.  A rectangle with inputs x0, y0, x1, y1 includes pixels x,y with x0 <= x < x1 and y0 <= y < y1.  The size is x1 - x0 by y1 - y0 pixels.

When outlines are added, the [NMT reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_rectangle.html) says "The outline lies inside the rectangle on its top and left sides, but outside the rectangle on its bottom and right side." This reference, normally excellent, is wrong here, at least on Windows with 3.5.1 and tk 8.6.4.  It is possible, however, that create_rectangle behavior depends on the native rectangle widgets of the OS.  If so, I'd like to know.

On my system, the rule above is true for a border of 1, but the addition of each outline layer alternates which lines are added inside and which outside. Using a good magnifier and the following code, I determined the start and stop values of the on-screen rectangles for various outline widths.  (I looked into using the .bbox method, but it seems to be off by 1 sometimes.)

```
'''find actual coordinates of canvas rectangle'''

import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

def report(event):
    print(event.x, event.y)

c = tk.Canvas(root)
c.grid()
w = 0
c.create_rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200, outline='red', fill='yellow',width=0)
c.bind('<Motion>', report)
```

Results (using one number for both x and y)

```
w start stop
0   100  200
1   100, 201
2    99, 201
3    99, 202
10   95, 205
```

The corrections needed are `w//2` for start and `(w+1)//2` for stop.  The following line should produce rectangles that are the same overall for any width less that half the narrowest size of the rectangle.

```
c.create_rectangle(100+(w//2), 100+(w//2), 200-(w+1)//2, 200-(w+1)//2,
                   fill='yellow', outline='red', width=w)
```

Comment: Very good answer much thanks for spending some time helping me and even coming up with the correct offsets, saved me a precious time. I wish however TK would behave like that DOC you pointed out, would be much better, but again as you said there's maybe some micro$oft behind this if its calling GDI APIs or other native windows stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The pictures suggests that `x0`, `y0` decrease by `width / 2` and `x1`, `y1` increase by the same amount. Now it looks like the canvas draws in exact pixels without any anti-aliasing so some rounding will be necessary and I am not sure how it will be done. If you want pixel accuracy you might need some trial and error to get everything in the right place.

Comment: For python 3 or python 2 with the integer division future import, use `//` instead of `/`.  From my experiments, reported in my answer, the `x1, y1` increase is `(width+1)//2.